# Поисковый робот google

Tags: seo, crawling

Ситуация следующая: имеются две версии сайта, мобильная и десктопная с разными url. Для десктопной версии имеются meta описания страниц, для мобильной версии их нет.

Теперь, если я с мобильного браузера в google нахожу какую нибудь страницу своего сайта, он даёт url мобильной версии страницы но meta описание подтягивает с десктопной версии.

И я не могу понять, почему это происходит, в рекомендациях google говорит о том, что meta теги должны быть прописаны для каждой страницы на обеих версиях сайта. Тоесть если он найдёт мобильную версию страницы, то и meta данные подтянет с неё, а на деле происходит, как я описал выше.

Вопрос в том, почему так происходит

Answer (score 0):

Весьма вероятно, что google "склеил" обе версии сайта и использует в сниппете данные с того сайта, где они являются более релевантными. А в случае, когда на мобильном сайте meta не заполнены, то более релевантным является описание с десктопной версии.